# Return bit-level equivalent of expression -f for floating point argument f

Tags: c, floating-point, negate

This is a homework question and I'm completely out of ideas (C programming).

Instructions:

```
/* 
 * float_neg - Return bit-level equivalent of expression -f for
 *   floating point argument f.
 *   Both the argument and result are passed as unsigned int's, but
 *   they are to be interpreted as the bit-level representations of
 *   single-precision floating point values.
 *   When argument is NaN, return argument.
 *   Legal ops: Any integer/unsigned operations incl. ||, &&. also if, while
 *   Max ops: 10
 *   Rating: 2
 */
unsigned float_neg(unsigned uf) {

return 2;
```

I've tried simply going return -uf; and other things but I just have no idea what to do.

Help?

The following conditions may be assumed:

> 1. Uses 2s complement, 32-bit representations of integers.
> 2. Performs right shifts arithmetically.
> 3. Has unpredictable behavior when shifting an integer by more
>       than the word size.

-EDIT

Solved it: return uf^0x80000000;

Comment: Check out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format - you need to flip the top bit of the input and return the result, unless the input is a NaN

Comment: If that comment was written by your teacher it sure is confusing.

Comment: It's worth noting that the "negation" this assignment defines is contrary to the IEEE-754 standard, which specifies that negation should flip the sign bit of the encoding for all inputs, including NaNs (§5.5.1 in 754-2008).

Answer (score 5):

Ignoring for now the absurdity of the question, the question is asking about the floating point format, presumably, the IEEE-754 standard that the Intel chips use. The binary format of the IEEE number for 32bits is:-

[image]

So, negating the value is trivial. Before toggling the top bit, you must check for various specific values: Nan, Inf, etc; and these are detailed in the IEEE specification.

Note that you can have +0 and -0.

Simply returning the integer negation won't work as that preforms a 2's complement negation, so integer value 1 becomes 0xffffffff which, when interpreted by the FPU would be a massively different value.

Comment: Just checking for NaN would be enough, right? Everything else can be negated?

Comment: @harold: best check the IEEE spec to make sure which special values have + and - values.

Comment: All of them, AFAIK. It's just that the comment says that NaNs should be returned unchanged, otherwise their sign could have been changed too. But I'll go check again.

Comment: @harold Yes, indeed. No need to check for infs and stuff.