# Bit-level expression for single precision floating point negation

Tags: floating-point, bit-manipulation, unsigned-integer

So I'm having a hard time implementing this idea.  I basically just want to take the argument 'uf' and negate it.  I am treating the argument as an unsigned integer in 32bit, this acts as a sort of equivalence to what a single precision floating point number would look like.  Should work the same: signed bit, 8 bits of exponent, 23 bits of fractional.

However, when the argument is NaN, I need to just return the argument.
Ideally I want to be able to implement this without any casting or high level operations.  Apparently I should be able to do it with just bitwise operations, and integer/unsigned operations (if, while, ||, &&).

I'm not sure where to start with this?  Would I just need to extract each part of 'uf' and negate them all separately (using bitwise operators), then add them all together at the end?  I'll likely use (~uf) + 1 for negation.

For NaN I recognize that I just need to check for all 1s in the 8bit part (exp) and anything but 0 in the fractional part (otherwise it's considered infinity).

As a reiteration, this is done in C for a 32 bit system.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Return bit-level equivalent of expression -f for floating point argument f](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12598205/return-bit-level-equivalent-of-expression-f-for-floating-point-argument-f)

Comment: I guess this must be a popular homework question because we've had a lot of similar questions in recent months - try searching SO as this has already been covered in great depth more than once.

Comment: I still don't get this homework assignment. `NaN ^ 0x80000000` is still `NaN`, so why does it have to be returned unmodified?

Comment: @harold: Presumably the reason the routine must return the argument when it is a NaN is because the specification for the routine says the routine must return the argument when it is a NaN. The fact that the “negation” of a NaN is also a NaN does not make it okay to violate the specification. For a homework assignment, one reason to give such a specification is to exercise the student’s understanding of how bits in the representation of a floating-point number are interpreted, by making them distinguish a NaN from a number.

Comment: @EricPostpischil no I'm sorry, I still deny the validity of the assignment. They could have picked any number of things that actually make sense, but instead they chose this. Bad assignment. (and obviously I meant "why is this assignment the way it is", not "why do we have to follow the assignment" - I mean seriously, how does that even make sense) harmonickey, which course is this for?

Comment: This is for Computer Systems.  This is to see how well you know what a floating point number is, and since you can't do this normal test with a float, we are doing it with an unsigned integer.  The idea is to use bitwise operations in combination with some other arithmetic operators.

Comment: Solution is below.  I will accept it after SO allows me to.

Answer (score 0):

```
x ^                        // flip signbit if not NaN
    (0x80000000 &          // isolate the signbit
      ~(                   // together, set signbit iff not NaN
         ((x & expmask) + expone) & // sets the signbit iff exp == 11111111
         -(x & mantmask))) // sets signbit only if the mantissa bits aren't zero
```

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is to flip the sign bit. I.e.

```
x ^ 0x80000000
```

If the value is a NaN, it is still a NaN even if you flip the sign bit.

Negation is not considered to be a floating point operation that requires you to return the same NaN as the input value, hence this is often generated by compilers for floating-point negation.

Answer (score 0):

I was actually able to find the correct solution.  All of these ideas helped.  However, we have to run a checker to validate our code and the only times it was wrong was when I had a zero as the signed bit and NaN was everything else.  Hence my check for (frac) != 0.

```
unsigned float_neg(unsigned uf) 
{

unsigned exp = (uf >> 23) & 0xFF;  //get only the exponential part of the number
unsigned frac = (uf << 9);  //get only the fractional part of the number
if ((exp == 0xFF) && (frac) != 0) 
{
  return uf; //NaN so return 'uf'
}

return uf ^ (1 << 31);  //just apply a simple sign change to the 's' component
}
```

Comment: Wait, you could use conditionals? I thought only bitmath. Well that just makes it trivial..

Comment: Yes, in the original post I said I could use if-statements.  However, even though I didn't say I could use == != it was implied, I suppose.  Even so... one could still perform them with bitmath i.e. == is !(x^y)